# AWS code deploy fails with error : specified file already exists at this

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I tried it for 2 cases

Using github as repository

1. Fresh deployment using codepipeline to desired location multiple time : files are overwritten automatically in this case by code deploy agent.
2. When files are manually created at install location(/var/www/html) then codedeploy throws error
   "*The deployment failed because a specified file already exists at this location: /var/www/html/abc.php*"

I am not able to overwrite files using for 2nd case ,

tried : `overwrite:true` -> this is not working

appspec.yml file

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html/
    overwrite: true
```

Comment: Error : The deployment failed because a specified file already exists at this location: /var/www/html/

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html/
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
```